# Why would my JavaScript function always return false?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the code to my application.

```
var seachHttp = function () {
                var cssSheets = document.styleSheets, // Loaded CSS Sheets
                    i =0, il = cssSheets.length, // Counter and limit for sheets
                    j, jl, rules, rule, // Counter and vars for Rules inside a Sheet
                    stylesToSearch = [ // Properties to Seach HTTP ON
                        'background',
                        'background-image',
                    ],
                    k, kl=stylesToSearch.length, // Counter for properties
                    s, // Current Property
                    v // Current Value;
                for(;i<il;i++) { // Loop Sheets
                    rules = cssSheets[i].rules || cssSheets[i].cssRules;
                    for(j=0,jl=rules.length;j<jl;j++) { // Loop Rules
                        rule = rules[j];
                        for(k=0;k<kl;k++){ // Loop Styles
                            s = stylesToSearch[k]; 
                            v = rule.style[s]; // Get Value from Current Style
                            if (  v !== undefined && v.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("http") > -1 ) { // Seach for HTTP Content
                                //alert("Found HTTP at " + rule.selectorText + " " + s + " = " + rule.style[s]);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Question is, why would the code above always return false although it should return true?

I then use conditions to check if the result is true or false.

This is the condtion I use to test for true or false:

```
if (div_array.length > 0 || seachHttp() == true) {
```

Could this be improved maybe?

Comment: Are you ever getting `alert()` inside `if`?

Comment: Have you done any debugging to determine what `v` is equal to prior to your final `if` statement?

Comment: It's a big function to try and process, but possibly the shortest way to discover the answer would be to place a debugger breakpoint next to `return false`. Then, when it breaks on that, check the variables nearby to see which of them don't match what you expect.

Comment: its wonderful how useful a `debugger` or `console.log()` statement is, have you tried either?

Comment: And please, use some more meaningful variables name: debugging something with variables `k`, `s`, and `v` is a nightmare came true.

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak  Yes the alert does bring up the data as expected when the statement is true.

Comment: @James Donnelly Not done that, but will try.

Comment: @Katana314 Good idea. Thanks.I just thought I was doing something simple which was wrong here

Answer (score 2):

You have `if () return true; else return false;`.  This means you only get to the first entry in all of the for loops and return from that.  You probably want `return false` after the for loops.

Answer (score 2):

the function effectively tests the first rule of the first selector of the first stylesheet **ONLY**

do not return false where you are returning false

return false at the end of the function

Answer (score 2):

Because you're returning false whenever you hit a rule with a value that doesn't match your true condition.  Essentially, as soon as you hit a background or background-image rule that doesn't contain 'http' your function will return false, even if later rules do meet your criteria.

Try returning a false value after your loops, and only return true if you hit your criteria.  See below for amendment.

```
var seachHttp = function () {
                var cssSheets = document.styleSheets, // Loaded CSS Sheets
                    i =0, il = cssSheets.length, // Counter and limit for sheets
                    j, jl, rules, rule, // Counter and vars for Rules inside a Sheet
                    stylesToSearch = [ // Properties to Seach HTTP ON
                        'background',
                        'background-image',
                    ],
                    k, kl=stylesToSearch.length, // Counter for properties
                    s, // Current Property
                    v;  // Current Value
                for(;i<il;i++) { // Loop Sheets
                    rules = cssSheets[i].rules || cssSheets[i].cssRules;
                    for(j=0,jl=rules.length;j<jl;j++) { // Loop Rules
                        rule = rules[j];
                        for(k=0;k<kl;k++){ // Loop Styles
                            s = stylesToSearch[k]; 
                            v = rule.style[s]; // Get Value from Current Style
                            if (  v !== undefined && v.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("http") > -1 ) { // Seach for HTTP Content
                                //alert("Found HTTP at " + rule.selectorText + " " + s + " = " + rule.style[s]);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```